# Simple toggle function issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to toggle the toggleTutorial function when user clicks the imgIcon, however, I can't even trigger the function.
I need my showTutorial variable to be gloabal variable but it seems if statement under getScript function doesn't trigger. Anyone here can help me out?

Thanks

```
$(function() {
    var spreadsheet = ''
    var showTutorial = true;
    $('.helpImgIcon').click(function() {
        $.getScript('inc/tutorial.js', function() {
            if (showTutorial) {
                toggleTutorial(showTutorial);
            }
        });
        showTutorial = false;
        return false;
    });
    $('body').click(function() {
        $('.js-tutorialTooltips').remove();
        $('.helpImg').remove();
        showTutorial = true;
    })
})​
```

Comment: if you mean the click function isn't running at all.. make sure the JS is included at the end of the page before </body> or wrapped in $(document).ready(function(){}) - and instead of using a global you could toggle a class on the body (and use that for the check) it might end up being handy for styling too!

Answer (score 6):

`$.getScript` is asynchronous so `showTutorial` will be false when it hits the callback.

Try changing it to:

```
$('.helpImgIcon').click(function() {
    $.getScript('inc/tutorial.js', function() {
        if (showTutorial) {
            toggleTutorial(showTutorial);
            showTutorial = false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: and as well as my other comment, this is true :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the DOM, JavaScript can have some terrible namespacing issues. I almost always namespace my variables as I go, i.e.

```
window.namespace = {}; //Object Literal for namespace
window.namespace.showTutorial = true;
```